# Getting attributes from video element after page load

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I want to get the 'currentSrc' value from the video object.
That's my code

```
mounted: function () {
    this.$nextTick(function () {
      console.log(document.getElementById('video').currentSrc)
    });
  },
```

No matter what I do, I always get an `<empty string>`. Which is pretty strange due to the fact that when I do:

```
mounted: function () {
    this.$nextTick(function () {
      console.log(document.getElementById('video'))
    });
  },
```

I get in console this object with correct currentSrc attribute.

I tried to use created(), refs, rerendering page by changing element key value, and even timeout, but always I get `<empty string>` as a result.
When I tried doing @load on video element it just does not work at all.

Is there any way to get object values, right after page is rendered?

Comment: Hi, could you provide your html template also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first code snippet, `<video>.currentSrc` isn't yet set when you're trying to log it, as the video is loaded asynchronously. The second snippet just logs the `<video>` element itself, which the browser console automatically updates on change, which is why you see `currentSrc` populated.

The `<video>` element first has to load the video metadata from source before any data properties are available, and it emits a [`loadedmetadata` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/loadedmetadata_event) when that occurs. You could listen to that event in your `mounted` hook:

```js
export default {
  mounted: function() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      const video = document.getElementById('video')
      video.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", function() {
        console.log('currentSrc', video.currentSrc);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

If your site potentially had more than one `<video>` element with an `id` of `"video"` (e.g., the page had multiple Vue components that contain this `<video>`), it would be better to get a reference to the intended element with a [template ref](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref):

```html
<template>
  <video ref="myVideo"></video>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  mounted: function() {
    this.$nextTick(() => { // use arrow functions here to capture `this`!
      this.$refs.myVideo.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", () => {
        console.log('currentSrc', this.$refs.myVideo.currentSrc);
      });
    });
  }
}
</script>
```

[demo 1](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/WNpyywY)

If you're only trying to add an event listener, just use the [`v-on` directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-on) in the template (e.g., `v-on:loadedmetadata="METHOD"` or `@loadedmetadata="METHOD"` shorthand):

```html
<template>
  <video ref="myVideo" @loadedmetadata="logCurrentSrc"></video>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    logCurrentSrc() {
      console.log('currentSrc', this.$refs.myVideo.currentSrc);
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

[demo 2](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/mdWKKBx)